# How to store end edit my configuration file

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, configuration-files

I have an application (split in different websites that share the same data) that contains thousands of products in different categories. Every category has its features, and to describe them I have used an XML file, embedded in a class library. Its format is like that:

```
<category code="" name="">
<featureGroup code="" name="">
<feature code="" name="">
<feature code="" name="">
<feature code="" name="">
</featureGroup>
</category>
```

This is overly simplified, my real files are much more complicated than that. The problem with this approach is that I have to recompile every time I have to make a change and redistribute my library to every different website.

So I made the file a standalone XML file, but also with this approach I have to redistribute the file every time I make a change.

So I converted my XML file in many tables and store these informations in a Sql database, but this approach has many disadvantages: it's far less flexible because if I make a change in the structure of the file I also have to change tables, relationships, stored procedures, etc... another problem is that XML works well with sorting. If I want to change the order of my features I just have to cut and paste a line in a different positions, if I try to do the same in my database I have to add a Position column and then provide some tool to reorder items and that's really a great mess.

I don't know how to solve this problems, I really like the flexibility of XML, I like the possibility of accessing my database anywhere from every web site, but I can't find a way to merge these two approaches.

Thank you very much and sorry for my rusty english!

Comment: Maybe you could store your XML in a no-SQL database, for example Mongo. Might be a bit overkill for a single file, but it could give you the best of both approaches.

Comment: I thought about using a no-SQL database, but what about my sorting problem? How can I move features without using some Position property?

Comment: If you just store that single XML file, your can do your sorting stuff as you did previously with the actual XML file. The only benefit you gain from my proposal is that the file would be stored in a central place (the database), which makes distribution and maintenance easier. The rest of your solution would just work as it did previously where each website had their own XML file. It's not the ideal solution, but it could have the least impact on your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small web service (which is accessible like your database) and make it *serve* the contents of **one centrally stored** xml file. I.e it should have one single request which answers with your xml file.